# jQuery width input field bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I made a custom search block that slides out when you click on the search icon. When the search block opens for the first time there is a bug where the input field becomes 100% width of the whole screen for 1 second instead of only the search block.

[image]

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    var search_block = $('.search-block');
    var search_block_overlay = $('.search-block-overlay');

    $('#dashboard-sub-search').on('click', function() {

        search_block.animate({width: "toggle"}, 300);
        search_block.addClass("search-block-active");
        search_block_overlay.addClass("search-block-overlay-active");
    });

    $('#close-search').on('click', function() {
        search_block.animate({width: "toggle"}, 300);
        search_block.css({'display': 'none'});
        search_block_overlay.removeClass("search-block-overlay-active");
    });
});
```

```css
.search-block {
    display: none;
}

.search-header {
    display: flex;
}

.search-form {
    width: 100%;
}

.search-content {
    margin-left: 38px;
}

.close-search {
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 36px;
}

.search-block-active {
    display: block;
    background: white;
    position: absolute;
    width: 600px;
    height: 100vh;
    top: 0;
    padding: 30px;
}
.search-block-overlay {
    display: none;
}
.search-block-overlay-active {
    display: block;
    background-color: rgba(9, 30, 66, 0.54);
    width: calc(100% - 600px);
    height: 100vh;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.css">


<div class="dashboard-sub-top-search mt-4">
    <i id="dashboard-sub-search" class="fa fa-search dashboard-sub-search"></i>
</div>

<div class="search-block">
    <div class="search-header">
        <div class="close-search-block mr-3">
            <i id="close-search" class="fa fa-times close-search"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="search-form">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="search-content mt-5">
        <h6>Recent search history</h6>
    </div>


</div>
<div class="search-block-overlay"></div>
```

After the initial opening it is fine. It occurs only when it gets opened for the first time. I made the block with the following code:

How can I fix this?

Comment: I would like to see any relevant HTML as well, if possible.  Can you put in a link to a demo so this can be seen in action?  Alternately, you can make a snippet in your post as well.

Comment: @DougF I edited the question

Comment: Just curious, why not use `search_block.removeClass("search-block-active");` instead of `search_block.css({'display': 'none'});`?

Comment: Thanks.  What browser were you using for your original screenshot?  I'm using Chrome and the textbox seems to not stretch the entire width.  At least that's how it's appearing in the snippet.

Comment: In any case, try running `search_block.addClass("search-block-active");`, then `search_block.animate({width: "toggle"}, 300);`. The problem is that "search-block-active" defines the width, and so `animate` doesn't know the width when it starts animating.

Comment: I am using chrome. You need to look very carefully. It stretches to 100% width of the screen for a fraction of a second.

Comment: @HereticMonkey, In that case, the block disappears and it does the complete opposite

Comment: Neat! :) Maybe put everything except for the `display` property into the `search-block` rule. I feel like the problem is that toggling those other properties is somehow the cause of the problem...

Comment: @HereticMonkey can you clarify what you mean by "put everything except for the display property into the search-block rule"?

Comment: I'll put it in an answer, like I should...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the code, working as desired (I hope).

What I did was move the code for the `search-block-active` (except the `display` property) out of that class and to `search-block` (same with `search-block-overlay`).

This may seem counter-intuitive: `search-block` has `display: none`, so why would it matter if it has a `width` defined? The trick is in the way `animate` works. It looks at the defined width of the block it's animating and basically calculates the steps (interim widths) needed to get from 0 to that width, and sets the width to those steps every x milliseconds, over the total you've given it.

So, now that we've told jQuery how wide it will be, it can calculate the correct amount to animate in each step.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    var search_block = $('.search-block');
    var search_block_overlay = $('.search-block-overlay');

    $('#dashboard-sub-search').on('click', function() {

        search_block.animate({width: "toggle"}, 300);
        search_block.addClass("search-block-active");
        search_block_overlay.addClass("search-block-overlay-active");
    });

    $('#close-search').on('click', function() {
        search_block.animate({width: "toggle"}, 300);
        search_block.css({'display': 'none'});
        search_block_overlay.removeClass("search-block-overlay-active");
    });
});
```

```css
.search-block {
    display: none;
    background: white;
    position: absolute;
    width: 600px;
    height: 100vh;
    top: 0;
    padding: 30px;
}

.search-header {
    display: flex;
}

.search-form {
    width: 100%;
}

.search-content {
    margin-left: 38px;
}

.close-search {
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 36px;
}

.search-block-active {
    display: block;
}
.search-block-overlay {
    display: none;
    background-color: rgba(9, 30, 66, 0.54);
    width: calc(100% - 600px);
    height: 100vh;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
.search-block-overlay-active {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.css">


<div class="dashboard-sub-top-search mt-4">
    <i id="dashboard-sub-search" class="fa fa-search dashboard-sub-search"></i>
</div>

<div class="search-block">
    <div class="search-header">
        <div class="close-search-block mr-3">
            <i id="close-search" class="fa fa-times close-search"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="search-form">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="search-content mt-5">
        <h6>Recent search history</h6>
    </div>


</div>
<div class="search-block-overlay"></div>
```